# Seraching for an alternative to annotatorjs.org

Tags: annotations, comments

following situation:

I have a website and would like customers to be able to annotate that like it is possible in google docs. Means: Mark a text and do a comment. I have already searched a lot and found http://annotatorjs.org/ which would be perfect for my needs but the problem is that development seems to have stopped back in 2016 and i don´t want to use components that are already not developed anymore by the date of implementation.
Does anyone have an idea ? I really searched a lot but i mostly find picture annotations which are not what i´m searching for.

Software as a service would also be an option.

Thanks, Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/recogito/recogito-js

The project seems to be healthy and maintained.